# System.Diagnostics.Process issue with WorkingDirectory

Tags: process, system.diagnostics, processstartinfo

I am using a third party software tool (command line tool) to merge PDF files together. Using C# I am attempting to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to run the executable but I am coming up with a few errors depending on the parameter setup.

- If `UseShellExecute = true` and `RedirectStandardOutput = true` I get:

  - The Process object must have the `UseShellExecute` property set to `false` in order to redirect IO streams.
- If `UseShellExecute = true` and `RedirectStandardOutput = false` I get:

  - The system cannot find the file specified
- If `useShellExecute = false` and `RedirectStandardOutput = true` I get:

  - The system cannot find the file specified
- If `UseShellExecute = false` and `RedirectStandardOutput = false` I get:

  - The system cannot find the file specified

The code that is running is the following:

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VeryPDF PDF Split-Merge v3.0";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdfpg.exe " + strFileNames.Trim() + " " 
                       + D2P_Folder_Converted + "\\" + strOutputFileName;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
p.Dispose();
```

Can someone help me get around this issue, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments shouldn't be passed in the [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx) property. You should use the [Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) property for this:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(
    "{0} {1}", 
    strFileNames.Trim(), 
    Path.Combine(D2P_Folder_Converted, strOutputFileName)
);
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(GetProgramFilesX86(), "VeryPDF PDF Split-Merge v3.0");
p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdfpg.exe";
```

where the `GetProgramFilesX86` function is could be defined like so:

```
static string GetProgramFilesX86()
{
    var processorArchitecture = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");
    if(IntPtr.Size == sizeof(long) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(processorArchitecture))
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)");
    }
    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles");
}
```

Comment: This suggestion merged with Kevin Gales "@" suggestion worked great. Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 8):

When `UseShellExecute` is `false` the `WorkingDirectory` property changes its meaning!

It becomes the working directory for the new process **NOT** the path to the executable. You need to specify the full path to the executable in the `FileName` property instead.

Comment: Well see I initially tried your suggestion but then I was recieving the "The system cannot find the file specified" error.

This is what I had originally:
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VeryPDF PDF Split-Merge v3.0\\pdfpg.exe " + strFileNames.Trim() + " " + D2P_Folder_Converted + "\\" + strOutputFileName;

Comment: See Kevin's comment - you need to put the arguments to the executable in the Arguments property. Reference for the UseShellExecute problem is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx

Comment: Thank you james, I was struggling on this..... how stupid of them to change the meaning of WorkingDirectory  when UseShellExecute is disabled!

Comment: Or you can use Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(). Works when you have an argument pointing to a file in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert using the process API but it looks like you are placing command line arguments into the FileName. Try using Arguments for the command line arguments. And put the full path to the exe in the FileName.

Also using an @ in front of the string gets rid of the need for the doubling of backslashes.

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\VeryPDF PDF Split-Merge\pdfpg.exe"
```